# High resolution display give incorrect viewport when snapping (Surface Pro)

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I just got to test IE10 on a Surface Pro with 1920*1080 display resolution where "make text and other items larger or smaller" has been set to Large.
On my website I have added the CSS+JS viewport fix in addition to the viewport meta tag, all asking for width: device-width (plus I added a "min-width: 320px;" to the @-ms-viewport definition to ensure it never gets smaller than that).

I added some javascript to display the value of window.screen.width and $(window).width to see what the browser ended up using for viewport in IE10, and to my surprise the screen size of a 1920*1080 resolution display was reported as 1280x720!

Now, I can live with with that (just like small phone screens report 320px width no matter their actual resolution, since it is a good size to make stuff human readable across devices for the same font size), but when the 'Metro IE10' is snapped to the side of the screen, the problem comes: IE10 tries to make a 320px rendering of the website, but it zooms in so the right side of it is hidden.

I tried Microsofts own test page: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/MakeItSnappy/
It does the same thing - on the Surface Pro the right side is hidden, and you need to drag left/right to see it, and you cannot even zoom out to view the full width!
But when trying the same thing on my laptop with a 'normal' 1366x768 display (rendered as 100%), the snapped IE10 display has the perfect size.

Ok, I guess this is a Microsoft Windows scaling bug - but my question is: Has anybody else experimented with changing the "make text and other items larger or smaller" to 125% or 150% and making websites adapt correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fix from developer Matt Stow

http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html